# Doubt in proving the uniform continuity of function

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, uniform-continuity

> Proof/disproof $f(x)=x+\cos \sqrt x  $ is uniformly continuity on $[0, \infty ).$

My approach:  By definition, for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exist a $\delta >0 $ such that $ |f(x_1)-f(x_2) | \leq \epsilon $ whenever $ |x_1-x_2| \leq \delta , \forall x_1 , x_2 \in [0, \infty )$
So,
$$ | x_1+\cos \sqrt x_1 - x_2-\cos \sqrt x_2| \leq |x_1- x_2|+|-2\sin \frac{(\sqrt x_1-\sqrt x_2)}{2}\sin \frac{(\sqrt x_1+\sqrt x_2)}{2}|\leq |x_1- x_2|+ 2\frac{|(\sqrt x_1-\sqrt x_2)|}{2}\frac{|(\sqrt x_1+\sqrt x_2)|}{2} \leq \frac{3}{2}|x_1- x_2| \leq \frac{3}{2}\delta =\epsilon$$

as $\sin x \leq x, \forall x \geq 0.$

Hence the function is uniformly continuous on $[0, \infty )$.

Is my approach correct or I had a mistake somewhere?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\epsilon$ is given and you have to find $\delta $ in terms of it. You cannot take $\delta=\epsilon -2$ because this may be negative.

Comment: You are almost there. You have to use the fact that $|\sin(x)\sin(y)|\leq |x|$ for all $x$ and all $y$.

Comment: Where did the square roots go?

Comment: I have edit the answer, please check now is it correct?